# ASP.Net MVC change default string ID to and int using docs get error tho

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I made a basic ASP.Net MVC Web project.
I switched all my IDs from `string` to an `int` with the Microsoft docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#run

I did these changes + the MVC Update 3 changes.
When I compile and run my new project it shows as an `int` in my file but I get an error and cannot finish running the project.

This is what my messages display in output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Input string was not in a correct format.

Any input would be appreciated. I did ran migrations and it shows up as `int` but doesn’t run in my browser fully.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                    .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => 
                        user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager), 
                        getUserIdCallback:(id)=>Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                }
            });
```

My code breaks in this part and that is the exception
id.GetUserId()

This is in startup.auth.cs

Thank you.

Comment: It is very hard to determine what could be the error without bits of code where it is going wrong.Please be clear about the question

Comment: Show us line where error occurs

Comment: Sorry everyone, now updated

Comment: Is this code first or db first ?

Comment: code the db isnt created until i run the project and I never successfully ran the project yet so no db is even their yet.
this is my error
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Try this: `(id)=>Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Make it culture-insensitive by providing second parameter value CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: Thank you RAHUL SHARMA!!!!
You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to put it as an answer to your question, the `Parse` method uses the current locale to convert your string to integer. I would guess that in your case, the `GetUserID()` would be in a format that your current locale would expect a comma as decimal point. Hence giving the optional parameter `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would make your locale culture-insensitive. An alternative would be provide a second optional parameter to provide a [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_).

To resolve your error, set this line as:

```
(id)=>Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For more information on [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_InvariantCulture).

Cheers.

Comment: My program was working fine for awhile and I never even touched this since i fixed it with you now all a sudden I am getting this error again the same one and I never touched anything in this I added a controller with new views but they quit getting loaded cuz this error again

                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => 
                        user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                        getUserIdCallback:(id) => Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId(),
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    )

Comment: @Bigbear You're converting a number to an integer. So if your `id.GetUserId()` is 4.5 for example,that would fail, because it's not an integer. Therefore use `Int32.TryParse()` in your case because `Int32.TryParse()` will return a value that will tell you whether parsing succeeded or not.

Comment: How would I put that in my part of my program? getUserIdCallback:(id) => Int32.TryParse(id.GetUserId(),
                     //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @Bigbear See this simple example for `TryParse`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DTnA2H. In your code, you would need to check first if your conversion of `id.GetUserId()` succeeded or not. Based on the boolean value that you get from this method, you can handle your scenarios appropriately. Then you wont even need to set your `id.GetUserId()` like you are doing right now. If the conversion succeeded, then set: `getUserIdCallback:(id)=>id.GetUserId())`, else `//handle if conversion did not succeed`

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question.

In my startup.auth.cs

I followed all the microsoft docs as I earlier stated.

I kept getting an error when I ran my project.

Adding CultureInfo as a second parameter on my ConfigureAuth() under CookieAuth.

Here is my finishing project code.

```
                     {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                    .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>
                    (
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => 
                        user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager), 
                        getUserIdCallback:(id) => Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId(), 
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        //getUserIdCallback:(id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                    )
                }
```